# Does the grpc async server has a better performance compared to the sync server with a restricted number of threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, grpc, rpc

I need to implement a server to which multiple clients can send requests simultaneously. The code processing an individual request might block (with the thread going to sleep) in the middle.

At the moment I am using the `C++ GRPC` synchronised server. Each time a client sends a request, a new thread is spawned on the server's side. This is a problem since a server can create too many threads simultaneously.

I am considering two solutions to avoid the problem:

1) Use the sync server with the `ResourceQuota` (e.g. restrict the max number of threads to 10).

2) Use the async server.

Implementing the second solution is considerably more difficult than implementing the first solution. **What advantage (if any) the second solution would give compared to the first one?** Which solution would give better results in terms of:

- The amount of time an individual client needs to wait to get a response to RPC
- The resources (memory, threads) used on the server.